# Having Issues Concatenating Strings into list without \n - Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently having some issues trying to append strings into a new list. However, when I get to the end, my list looks like this:

['MDAALLLNVEGVKKTILHGGTGELPNFITGSRVIFHFRTMKCDEERTVIDDSRQVGQPMH\nIIIGNMFKLEVWEILLTSMRVHEVAEFWCDTIHTGVYPILSRSLRQMAQGKDPTEWHVHT\nCGLANMFAYHTLGYEDLDELQKEPQPLVFVIELLQVDAPSDYQRETWNLSNHEKMKAVPV\nLHGEGNRLFKLGRYEEASSKYQEAIICLRNLQTKEKPWEVQWLKLEKMINTLILNYCQCL\nLKKEEYYEVLEHTSDILRHHPGIVKAYYVRARAHAEVWNEAEAKADLQKVLELEPSMQKA\nVRRELRLLENRMAEKQEEERLRCRNMLSQGATQPPAEPPTEPPAQSSTEPPAEPPTAPSA\nELSAGPPAEPATEPPPSPGHSLQH\n']

I'd like to remove the newlines somehow. I looked at other questions on here and most suggest to use .rstrip however in adding that to my code, I get the same output. What am I missing here? Apologies if this question has been asked.

My input also looks like this(took the first 3 lines):

> sp|Q9NZN9|AIPL1_HUMAN Aryl-hydrocarbon-interacting protein-like 1 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=AIPL1 PE=1 SV=2
>   MDAALLLNVEGVKKTILHGGTGELPNFITGSRVIFHFRTMKCDEERTVIDDSRQVGQPMH
>   IIIGNMFKLEVWEILLTSMRVHEVAEFWCDTIHTGVYPILSRSLRQMAQGKDPTEWHVHT

```
  from sys import argv 

protein = argv[1] #fasta file 

sequence = '' #string linker 
get_line = False #False = not the sequence 
Uniprot_ID = []
sequence_list =[]
with open(protein) as pn:
    for line in pn: 
        line.rstrip("\n")
        if line.startswith(">") and get_line == False:
            sp, u_id, name = line.strip().split('|')
            Uniprot_ID.append(u_id) 
            get_line = True 
            continue
        if line.startswith(">") and get_line == True:
            sequence.rstrip('\n')
            sequence_list.append(sequence) #add the amino acids onto the list
            sequence = ''  #resets the str
        if line != ">" and get_line == True: #if the first line is not a fasta ID and is it a sequence? 
            sequence += line 
print(sequence_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip), `rstrip` removes *trailing* characters – the ones at the end. You probably misunderstood others' use of it to remove `\n`s because typically those would *only* appear at the end.

To replace a character with something else in an entire string, use [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) instead.

These commands do **not** modify your string! They return a *new* string, so if you want to change something 'in' a current string variable, assign the result back to the original variable:

```
>>> line = 'ab\ncd\n'
>>> line.rstrip('\n')
'ab\ncd'        # note: this is the immediate result, which is not assigned back to line
>>> line = line.replace('\n', '')
>>> line
'abcd'
```

Comment: Thank you! Importing re and adding the code: "sequence = re.sub('\n', '',sequence)" removed the \n.

Comment: @CluelessCoder: why prefer a regex when a basic `replace` will do just fine?

Comment: When I asked this question I didn't take my time in looking at documentation & my code. After looking at my code, I realized two things: 1. my code isn't actually getting what I am interested in. 2) for the particular question I asked I could have simply use line.split(). Edited code is below

Answer (score 0):

When I asked this question I didn't take my time in looking at documentation & understanding my code. After looking, I realized two things:

1. my code isn't actually getting what I am interested in.
2. For the specific question I asked, I could have simply used line.split() to remove the '\n'.

   ```
   sequence = '' #string linker 
   get_line = False #False = not the sequence 
   uni_seq = {}
   """this block of code takes a uniprot FASTA file and creates a
   dictionary with the key as the uniprot id and the value as a sequence""" 
   with open (protein) as pn:
       for line in pn: 
           if line.startswith(">"):
               if get_line == False:
                   sp, u_id, name = line.strip().split('|')
                   Uniprot_ID.append(u_id)
                   get_line = True 
               else:
                   uni_seq[u_id] = sequence
                   sequence_list.append(sequence)
                   sp, u_id, name = line.strip().split('|')
                   Uniprot_ID.append(u_id)
                   sequence = '' 
           else:
               if get_line == True: 
               sequence += line.strip() # removes the newline space 
   uni_seq[u_id] = sequence
   sequence_list.append(sequence)
   ```